# Getting value from a form to create a node in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm trying to add some Nodes with a PHP form but I'm note quite sure about the way to do it.

What I'm trying to do is to get the value of different elements from a standard form, each value is set as a Node in order to be append.

It would allow me to create (in my example) another person with a name and a comment in my XML.

The MAMP error log is telling me these errors :

```
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 30
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 30
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: comment in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 31
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 31
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 5
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php on line 6
[19-Dec-2016 16:11:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, instance of stdClass given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-php/form.php:16
```

It seems that the way I'm trying to get the values of my form isn't working. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

My PHP

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


     $name->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];
     $comment->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];

     $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
     $xml->formatOutput = true; 
     $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
     $xml->load('examples.xml');

     $inventors = $xml->getElementsByTagName('inventors')->item(0);
     $person_inventor = $xml->createElement('person');
     $name_inventor = $xml->createElement('name');
     $name_inventor->appendChild($name);
     $comment_inventor = $xml->createElement('comment');
     $comment_invenotr->appendChild($comment);
     $person_inventor->appendChild($name_inventor);
     $person_inventor->appendChild($comment_inventor);
     $inventors->appendChild($person_inventor);

     htmlentities($xml->save('examples.xml'));

 }

 ?>

 <form method="POST" action=''>
     name <input type="text-name" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue?>" name="namanya" />
     comment  <input type="text-comment" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue?>"  name="commentnya"/>
     <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventors>
 <person>
  <name>anie</name>
  <comment>good</comment>
 </person>
</inventors>
```

Comment: Try creating elements of *$name* and *$comment* at top prior to using `nodeValue`.

Comment: @Parfait Yeah I wrote : 
       $name = $_POST['namanya'];
       $comment = $_POST['commentnya'];

Comment: However, I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues arise with current setup:

1. Referencing variables, *$name* and *$comment* that are never initialized, hence the *Undefined variable* notice.
2. Misspelling of *$comment_invenotr*.
3. The method `appendChild()` is not used for values but elements.

Consider adjusting such variable references and even their order in code. And since it seems you want to assign the `$_POST` values to node text, consider one of two ways:

**createElement Argument**

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');     
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;     
$xml->load('examples.xml');

$inventors = $xml->getElementsByTagName('inventors')->item(0);
$person_inventor = $xml->createElement('person');

$name_inventor = $xml->createElement('name', $_POST['namanya']);     
$comment_inventor = $xml->createElement('comment', $_POST['commentnya']);

$person_inventor->appendChild($name_inventor);
$person_inventor->appendChild($comment_inventor);
$inventors->appendChild($person_inventor);

htmlentities($xml->save('examples.xml'));
```

**nodeValue Assignment**

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');     
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;     
$xml->load('examples.xml');

$inventors = $xml->getElementsByTagName('inventors')->item(0);
$person_inventor = $xml->createElement('person');

$name_inventor = $xml->createElement('name');     
$name_inventor->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];

$comment_inventor = $xml->createElement('comment');
$comment_inventor->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];

$person_inventor->appendChild($name_inventor);
$person_inventor->appendChild($comment_inventor);
$inventors->appendChild($person_inventor);

htmlentities($xml->save('examples.xml'));
```

Comment: I also had to change the PHP form to delete the value attribute to delete other error logs ! Huge thanks for your help.